# "babel-plugin-react-intl" is not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-intl, babel-plugin-react-intl

I have created my react app using `create-react-app` command. Now I would like to available my website in both hindi and english language.
So for that I am using `yahoo/react-intl`. I have also installed the babel-plugin-react-intl plugin. Also added the .babelrc file.

My `.babelrc` file look like:

```
{
"presets": ["es2015", "react"],
"plugins": [
  [
    "react-intl",
    {
      "messagesDir": "./build/messages/"
    }
  ]
]
}
```

But I am not getting the extracted messages from my js file to `./build/messages/`.

I dont know where I made a mistake.

My index.js is:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { IntlProvider, addLocaleData } from "react-intl";
import hi from "react-intl/locale-data/hi";
import en from "react-intl/locale-data/en";

import registerServiceWorker from "./registerServiceWorker";
import Hello from "./components/Hello";

addLocaleData([...en, ...hi]);

ReactDOM.render(
  <IntlProvider locale="hi" messages={/*comming soon*/}>
    <Hello />
  </IntlProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

And all my js-files are inside the components folder.

Foe example my `Hello.js` component looks like:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { FormattedMessage } from "react-intl";

class Hello extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>
          <FormattedMessage id="Hello.heading" defaultMessage="Hello world" />
        </h1>
        <p>
          <FormattedMessage
            id="Hello.paragraph"
            defaultMessage="This is my world"
          />
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Hello;
```

My `package.json` is:

```
{
"name": "i18n-myexamplae",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
  "react": "^16.4.2",
  "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
  "react-intl": "^2.4.0",
  "react-scripts": "1.1.4"
},
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-plugin-react-intl": "^2.4.0"
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `react-scripts` don't use your `.babelrc`. You either need to eject because then you're allowed to edit `.babelrc` config or you need to run babel manually.

Run `./node_modules/.bin/babel src --out-dir lib` and ignore/delete everything in `--out-dir`. You're doing this only to extract messages. Also, to make build consistent, replace your `es2018` and `react` presets with `react-app` preset, which is the one used by `create-react-app`.

**NOTE:** when using `react-app` preset you actually need to run `NODE_ENV=development ./node_modules/.bin/babel src --out-dir lib`, because `react-scripts` require NODE_ENV to be configured. You can add this to you `package.json` to make things easier.

```
"scripts": {
  "extract": "NODE_ENV=development babel src --out-dir lib",
  ...
},
```

---

I faced a similar issue in i18n library I'm writing, [lingui](https://lingui.js.org/). `lingui extract` command is checking if a project uses `create-react-app` and if so, it uses `react-app` preset automatically for extracting messages.

Comment: Thank you @Tomas Ehrlich

Comment: But It is creating a lib folder. Is it necessary to create that folder.

Comment: No, that's just a side-effect of babel compiling src dir. Either ignore it or delete it right away: `NODE_ENV=development babel src --out-dir lib && rm -r lib`

Comment: Hi, running 'npm run extract' gives the error, NODE_ENV is not recognized as an internal or external command @Tomas.

Comment: @DivisionSi You probably need cross-env package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env. Then the command is `cross-env NODE_ENV=development babel src --out-dir lib`